# Copy non-contiguous columns onto Sheet2 and form a vertical stacking table

Tags: vba, excel

Everything works as expected.

This will look for the value of `pptText` in `Sheet1` and then copy it onto `Sheet2` to form a table.  I will add something that copies then pastes the tables on `Sheet2` onto another sheet after each iteration of the arrayLoop, but this works for now.

This is what `Sheet1` looks like:

[image]

And this is what `Sheet2` looks like after running this code:

[image: Sheet2]

Any help scrubbing/shortening/or making this code faster, smoother and more efficient is appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub chkPercent()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ShRef As Worksheet
    Dim ShWork As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ShRef = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set rng = ShRef.Range("A1")
    Dim iq_Array As Variant
    Dim colNumb As Long
    Dim rowNumb As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    colNumb = ShRef.Cells(1, ShRef.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    rowNumb = ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iQRef() As String
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim pptText As String

    ReDim iQRef(colNumb)
    ' capture IQ refs locally
    For iCol = 2 To colNumb
        iQRef(iCol) = ShRef.Cells(1, iCol).Value
    Next iCol

    Worksheets.Add After:=ShRef
    Set ShWork = wb.Worksheets(2)

        pptText = "iq_9"

        'Identify if within text there is "iq_"
        'If InStr(1, pptText, "iq_") <= 0 Then GoTo nextShpe

        'set iq_Array as an array of the split iq's
        iq_Array = Split(pptText, ",")

        Dim hasIQs As Boolean
        Dim checkStr As String
        Dim pCol As Long
        Dim checkOne
        Dim arrayLoop As Long

        checkOne = iq_Array(0)

        hasIQs = Left(checkOne, 3) = "iq_"

        If hasIQs Then
            ' paste inital column into temporary worksheet
            ShRef.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Columns(1)
        End If

        ' loop for each iq_ in the array
        For arrayLoop = LBound(iq_Array) To UBound(iq_Array)
            ' Take copy of potential ref and adjust to standard if required
            checkStr = iq_Array(arrayLoop)
            If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr

            Dim iQRefArray As Variant
            Dim iQRefString As String
            Dim checkRefStr As String
            Dim nCol As Long
            Dim doUntilCheck As String
            Dim rowCount As Long
            Dim copy1
            Dim paste1
            doUntilCheck = 99
            ' Look for existence of corresponding column in local copy array
            pCol = 0
            For iCol = 2 To colNumb

                iQRefString = Left(iQRef(iCol), Len(iQRef(iCol)) - 1)
                iQRefArray = Replace(iQRefString, "__", "_")
                iQRefArray = Split(iQRefArray, "_")
                checkRefStr = "iq_" & iQRefArray(1)

                If checkStr = checkRefStr Then
                    pCol = iCol
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iCol

            If pCol > 0 Then

                ' Paste the corresponding column into the forming table
                ShRef.Columns(pCol).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Columns(2)

                If iQRefArray(2) = "00" Then GoTo nxtArrayLoop

                nCol = 0

                rowCount = 1

                Do Until doUntilCheck = "00"
                    Do Until doUntilCheck = "01"

                    nCol = nCol + 1

                    rowCount = rowCount + rowNumb

                    iQRefString = Left(iQRef(iCol + nCol), Len(iQRef(iCol + nCol)) - 1)
                    iQRefArray = Replace(iQRefString, "__", "_")
                    iQRefArray = Split(iQRefArray, "_")

                    doUntilCheck = iQRefArray(2)
                    If doUntilCheck = "00" Then GoTo nxtArrayLoop
                    If doUntilCheck = "01" Then GoTo nxtArrayLoop

                    ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(1, 1)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(rowCount, 1)
                    ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol + nCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(1, pCol + nCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(rowCount, 2)
                    Loop
                Loop
            End If

nxtArrayLoop:

        Next arrayLoop


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- Option Explicit - excellent! (this should be required in all modules, by default)
- `Sub chkPercent()` - should be declared explicitly Public (or Private), accordingly
- I found it hard to notice where `wb` was set
- `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` should be `Set wb =`**`ThisWorkbook`** (current file where the code is)
- Naming convention is a bit cryptic

  - I'm not sure what `iCol` signifies, or what `iQRef` is used for
  - `colNumb`, `rowNumb` should indicate that they refer to the last Row/Col
- Very nice use of arrays to speed things up with `iQRef()`, but

  - You're redimming it to all columns when you know you'll not be using the first 2
  - It doesn't cause any harm, but you have the first 2 elements unused
  - You're excluding the 2nd col because of your test data but only the 1st column should be excluded by default
- Most of the code is indented 2 levels, instead of just one - is this significant in any way?
- Makes the assumption that the main sheet (ShRef) is the first one in Worksheets collection

  > ```
  >  Worksheets.Add After:=ShRef
  >
  >  Set ShWork = wb.Worksheets(2)
  > ```
- `pptText` can safely be a CONST, using less resources and performing better

  > ```
  >  Dim pptText As String
  >
  >  pptText = "iq_9"
  > ```
- I'm not sure why you generate an array of a single element `iq_Array = Split(pptText, ",")`

  - I'm guessing you want to add more items later

    - If that's the case the implementation of the system is incomplete
  - It looks like you are preparing to have identifiers with different numbers
  - `hasIQs = Left(checkOne, 3) = "iq_"` but this is just complicating things
  - When all your identifiers could be declared like this

    - `Const TARGET_COL = "iq_3_,iq_7_,iq_9_,iq_11_"`, etc (don't need separate parsing)
- Comments can be very useful but don't describe WHAT the code is doing - it should be clear by reading the code
      * You'll end up maintaining 2 items: code AND comments

  - If the code or its purpose is not obvious, do describe WHY the code is doing something or why it does something unexpected
  - Comments should be replaced by intuitive naming convention for variable and procedure names that could replace comments by describing their purpose and usage
- Don't declare variables in loops; it adds unnecessary overhead for GC (garbage collector) for every iteration
- Very convoluted logic

  - You perform the same check twice: `If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then`
  - `checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr` results in `"iq_iq_9"`

    - The bug above is hidden because the conditions will never be true
    - Similar to `If "a" = "a" and "a" <> "a" Then`
- What's the significance of `doUntilCheck = 99`? Temporary statement to allow you to enter the `Do Until doUntilCheck = "00"` loop? (I had to hunt down the reason). 99 is a magic (random) number.
- There are way too many nesting levels of the most intensive work: **loops**

  - You have a `Do Until` inside another `Do Until`, inside a `For`

    - The outermost loop contains another `For` loop (!)
  - **The loops need the utmost attention and efficiency**
  - Remove all unnecessary logic from each and every loop
  - Don't add nesting layers unless absolutely necessary

    - This is where performance decreases exponentially (arrays or not)
- The inner `For`: are you expecting identifiers to contain `__`?:

  - `iQRefArray = Replace(iQRefString, "__", "_")`
  - How are the `__` relevant when you are only using the start of the identifier (iq_3_,iq_7_,iq_9_,iq_11_)?
- On the other hand, you do a lot of validation which is very good (I tend to do the same) but too much of it becomes very expensive so we need to look for the best balance
- The `GoTo` is a red flag - your flow is broken, now you start to jump, and the logic and motivation becomes extremely hard to follow (at least I wouldn't spend time trying to understand it)
- Repeating logic for processing column headers:

  > ```
  >  iQRefString = Left(iQRef(iCol + nCol), Len(iQRef(iCol + nCol)) - 1)
  >
  >  iQRefArray = Replace(iQRefString, "__", "_")
  >
  >  iQRefArray = Split(iQRefArray, "_")
  > ```
- You're overcautious and the redundancy doesn't produce the validation you expect

  - You are testing based on the identifier initial length `Left()` + `Len()`
  - Yet you want to remove any extra underscores AFTER the validation

    - If there are extra underscores the validation will fail on the first test
- **2 more `GoTo` statements** (somehow connected to the first)

  > ```
  >  doUntilCheck = iQRefArray(2)
  >
  >  If doUntilCheck = "00" Then GoTo nxtArrayLoop
  >
  >  If doUntilCheck = "01" Then GoTo nxtArrayLoop
  > ```

  - It looks like you want to do different processing for (or exclude) identifiers containing `00` and `01`? (is this an extra requirement?)
  - There are multiple ways to accomplish the task of GoTo, but require a bit more work - the price for being clear and making the code easy to maintain in the long run

---

This is how I would attempt to accomplish the task:

**Main Sub**:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransposeCols()
    Const START_COL = 2
    Const TARGET_COL = "iq_9_,iq_11_"

    optimizeXL True
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lc1 As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    With ws1.UsedRange
        lr1 = .Rows.Count
        lc1 = .Columns.Count
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, lc1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
    Set ws2 = GetWs2("Output", ws1)
    If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
        Dim lr2 As Long, c As Long, targets As Variant, tCol As Long, colOK As Boolean
        lr2 = GetLastRowInWs(ws2):  targets = Split(TARGET_COL, ",")
        With ws1.UsedRange
            For c = START_COL To lc1
                For tCol = 0 To UBound(targets)
                    If InStr(1, .Columns(c).Cells(1), targets(tCol)) > 0 Then
                        .Columns(c).Hidden = False
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Cells(lr2, 1)
                        .Columns(c).Hidden = True
                        lr2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            .Columns.Hidden = False: ws2.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit: ws2.Activate
        End With
    End If
    optimizeXL False
End Sub
```

**Helpers**:

```
Private Function GetWs2(ByVal wsName As String, ByRef AfterWs As Worksheet) As Worksheet
    If Len(wsName) > 0 And Not AfterWs Is Nothing Then
        If Not WSExists(wsName) Then
            Set GetWs2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=AfterWs)
            GetWs2.Name = wsName
        Else
            Set GetWs2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetLastRowInWs(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Long
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        With ws.UsedRange
            GetLastRowInWs = .Rows.Count
            If GetLastRowInWs > 1 Then
                .Rows.EntireRow.Delete
                GetLastRowInWs = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function WSExists(ByVal wsName As String) As Boolean
    If Len(wsName) > 0 Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = wsName Then
                WSExists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function

Public Sub optimizeXL(Optional ByVal settingsOff As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = Not settingsOff
        .Calculation = IIf(settingsOff, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .EnableEvents = Not settingsOff
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

Output:

[image: Sheet2]

---

At high level the code works by hiding all columns, except the first.

It loops all other columns (starting at col 2):

1. Check header of the currently processed column and if valid

   - Unhides current col  (we now have col1 and col2 visible)
   - Copies the 2 visible columns to result sheet, in first empty cell in column A
   - Hides the current column
2. Moves to the next column and repeats the steps above (1.)

---

[image: Step by step]

Comment: You are right, the code is supposed to copy the columns based on the column names. In the example I had, the code is looking for "iq_9" (`pptText`)and so it will extract every column with "iq_9" in the title and stack them. This is why the first column wasn't copied over, it's an "iq_7".

Comment: So a regular number is written like this "iq_10_01__A_" and I'll store each value into a four slotted array. So then in slot 2 (`iQRefArray(1)`) I'll look for the 10 and if slot 3 = 00 it means this is the only "iq_" of this number, if slot 3 = 01 it means that there is another one coming after it = "iq_10_02__A_". So I'll check to see if the 3rd array slot in the next "iq_" = 00 or 01 to find the end of the sequence and end the loop. I hope this helps, ask me any more clarification and I will try my best!